# Show that there is a simple group of order 9828

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Generally we know that some groups are not simple, with theorems of sylows, but they talk about prime power order groups, but as I prove for example that it has no normal subgroup of order 6 in some order group 9828 Using sylow?

Comment: Are you expected to be familiar with any of the famous families of simple groups? Alternating, projective special linear, etc

Comment: You cannot use Sylow's Theorem to prove the existence of a simple group of a specified order, only to derive some of its properties assuming that it does exist.

Answer (score 4):

$PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_{3^3})$ has the required order..

The point being $9828 = 2^2\cdot 3^3 \cdot 7 \cdot13 = 1/2 (26 \cdot 27 \cdot 28)= 1/2\{(3^3-1)\cdot3^3 \cdot(3^3+1)\}$.

Which is precisely the order of $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_{3^3}) = SL_2(\mathbb{F}_{3^3})/ \{\pm 1\}$.